# How can I show only outline for a Font Awesome icon?

Tags: html, css

I am working with the tag icon from FA http://fontawesome.io/icon/tag/ and what I wish to do is to display only the outline (red) of it and make the inside transparent. `fa-tag-o` does not work. I've also tried `fa-tag-empty` and CSS like

```
.fa{
   color: transparent;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
 }
```

but nothing seems to work. Is there any possible way I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: upload your code on jsfiddle

Comment: There is no particular code really. This is what I have at the moment: 
<i class="fa fa-tag fa-flip-horizontal fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"> which just displays the tag icon just horizontally flipped.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no tag like fa-tag-o  you can use **fa-tag or fa-tags** your code works fine.. U can use flip you can use rotate u can make ur own custom css tor fa-tag like I made a custom class for the second fa-custom  [livefiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgmx8m32/2/)
fa-4x here x means em so fa-4x means fa size 4em .

```css
.fa.fa-tag{
   color: transparent;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
 }
.fa.custom-fa{
 font-size:12em;
 -webkit-text-stroke-color: blue;
color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-tag fa-rotate-90 fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><br>

<i class="fa fa-tag fa-flip-horizontal custom-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I particularly need the tag icon not tags.

Comment: @L.D you can use fa-tag but there is no fa-tag-o in font awesome

Comment: Due to the fact @Bram Vanroy mentioned and also because what I really wanted was a solid outline and not a shadow I have to give the answer to you! Thanks

Answer (score 21):

If you know the background color beforehand, you can use `text-shadow`, and set the color of the icon to the background color.

```css
.fa-tag {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px red;
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i class="fa fa-tag fa-flip-horizontal fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

To make it more solid, apply the shadow twice:

```css
.fa-tag {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px red, 0px 0px 1px red;
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i class="fa fa-tag fa-flip-horizontal fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Though, is there any way I could make the red line look more solid since it is a shadow after all?

Comment: You can apply it twice - `text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px red, 0px 0px 1px red;`, and it will look more solid.

Comment: It speaks for itself, but I'd like to emphasise it, that this only works nicely if the color of the icon matches the background color. When you don' thave a solid background color (image, gradient) this wouldn't look as you want to. Therefore I think Mostafa's solution is better, yet less supported.

Answer (score 6):

you have to append -o 
ex: 
`fa fa-flag-o` instead of `fa fa-flag`

Comment: Very useful answer.

Comment: Not every icon has an outline option (-o).

Comment: Works in 2024 latest version of fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

Use below CSS

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-text-stroke : black; // can be any color
```