How to Optimize Font Awesome Icon: White Background, Black Border in Angular?
In an Angular project, I absolutely need to use icons from Font Awesome 5.

The color of the Ordres icon is perfect, however the background color for Portefeuille isn't attractive.
The problem is that fas fa-wallet is black, but I want it to have a white background and a black border.
Is it possible to achieve this, please?


do you have font awesome pro? or using the free version?

You can use CSS to achieve that. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317648/how-can-i-show-only-outline-for-a-font-awesome-icon

Try the code below to give the "fas fa-wallet" a white background and a black border.
Html file:
<i class='fas fa-wallet' style='font-size:80px; color:white; text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 black, 2px -2px 0 black, -2px 2px 0 black, 2px 2px 0 black;'></i>

